# LESS syntax highlighting in Geany

Tags: syntax-highlighting, less, geany

I'm using [LESS CSS](http://leafo.net/lessphp/) (PHP version). I'm also using Geany in Linux. Is there a LESS syntax file for Geany out there, or how I can go about editing the CSS one to suit LESS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work. Just update your configuration file filetype_extension.conf.

1. Open `~/.config/geany/filetype_extensions.conf`
2. Change this line: `CSS=*.css;` to this: `CSS=*.css;*.less;`
3. Save configuration file.

Comment: You can also edit directly from geany with `Tools > Configuration Files > filetype_extensions.conf`

Answer (score 6):

You can also add following into your ~/.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.css - file

[lexer_properties]
lexer.css.less.language=1

Comment: It works! At last, `nested rules` are highlighted, awesome :). To make it work, I created the file `filetypes.css`, copied the two lines in it, saved it, logged out and logged in again.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why this setting is not the default.

Answer (score 4):

This might be due to a different version, but from within Geany 0.20 you can go to the

```
main menu > Tools > Configuration Files > filetype_extensions.conf
```

Prior to accessing the filetype_extensions.conf file in this way the file did not exist in the above mentioned location. Once the changes are saved the file can be found there.